# How to compile Shadows events using MSBuild

Tags: events, msbuild, interop, shadows

I am trying to use set up a CI server that doesn't depend on a Visual Studio installation but uses msbuild instead. Our solution includes an interop project. Visual Studio handles this project just fine, but msbuild seems to have a problem with events like this one, taken from an interop user control which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl:

```
Public Shadows Event Click() 'Event must be marked as Shadows since .NET UserControls have the same name.
```

The error I get from MSBuild is this:
    error BC30029: Derived classes cannot raise base class events.

I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecakwbz.aspx), but my Event statement and RaiseEvent statements are already in the same class (the one from which the above error is being thrown). I don't think this solution applies to my situation.

What's the best way to get around this? Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: This error doesn't come from MSBuild, it comes from the compiler.  And it isn't caused by this statement, it is the code that calls RaiseEvent that's wrong.  Do use the IDE, it helps you locate the mistake in your code.  Just double-click the error message.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It compiles fine using the IDE.